# Intellij Removes amperand from href tag

Tags: intellij-idea, xhtml

In any xhtml file and inside an href tag when you try to place a parameter like `<a href="foo.xhtml?a=b&amp;c=d" >link</a>` the code reformat (I think) removes the **&** and its leaving me with `<a href="foo.xhtml?a=b amp;c=d" >link</a>` breaking my links.

Any idea how to bypass it?

Comment: Escape character? `\&`

Comment: Works fine for me. Which IDEA version? Are you sure it happens on re-format?

Comment: @stephen-friedrich Forgot to mention that it is actually a JSF page. Yes it happens in reformat, I have it on auto. The version is 15.0.4

@Harmelodic Escape does not work immediately when I press `&` it is converted to a whitespace  , I by passed it by replacing it with `%26`